# Need to return true to function from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
function check() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/info_controller/check_login',
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg == 'yes') {
                job = confirm('Do you want to book this time?');
                if (job == true) {
                    alert();

                }
            } else {
                $('.outer_table').css("opacity", 0.6).fadeIn(300, function () {
                    $('#login_confirm').show();

                });
                $('body').click(function () {
                    $('#login_confirm').hide();
                    $('body').css("opacity", 1);
                });

            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/info_controller/book/<?php echo $listinfo['days_id'];?>/<?php echo $listinfo['time_id'];?>" onclick="return check()";> <b><?php echo $listinfo['time']; ?></b></a>
```

This url index.php/info_controller/check_login checks whether the php session is active or not. if its active it returns msg 'yes'else 'no'.. If yes then it pops a confirm box and if i click ok it needs to return true to onclick funtion 'check' but it always returns false.
( i am using codeigniter framework by the way)

Comment: Post your controller function along with your model

Comment: function check_login(){

   if($this->session->userdata('id')!=''){

    echo 'yes';

   }

   else

    echo 'no';

 }

This doesnt have any functions related to model.